# Draw multiple chart in one page with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I need to show multiple chart from data which i get from ajax source. But i don't know why Chart.js only show one chart at a time although i made new dataset as well as new canvas for each chart. Please help me, this is the javascript code which i used to draw chart.

```
function showBarChart(label, index, key){
    var areaChartOptions = {
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,

        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines : true,

        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

        //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
        scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,

        //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
        scaleShowVerticalLines: true,

        //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
        barShowStroke : true,

        //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
        barStrokeWidth : 2,

        //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
        barValueSpacing : 5,

        //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
        barDatasetSpacing : 1,

        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",

        //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
        responsive: true,
        animationSteps: 15,
        scaleLabel: "          <%=value%>"
    };

    document.getElementById('metterpanel').innerHTML = '';
    for(i = 0; i < key.length; i++){
        var datakey = key[i];

        document.getElementById('metterpanel').innerHTML += ' <div class="col-md-2 ">' + '<div class="meter">' + '<div>' +
            ' <canvas id="' + datakey + '" style="height: 180px;"></canvas>' + ' <div class="ColProduct Product">' + '<div class="ProContent Pro-Name">' + datakey
            +' </div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>'+ '</div>';

        var startingData = {
            labels: [label[datakey]],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: datakey + ' Consumed',
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [index[datakey]]
                }
            ]
        };

        //-------------
        //- LINE CHART -
        //--------------
        var lineChartCanvas = $("#"+datakey).get(0).getContext("2d");
        var datakey = new Chart(lineChartCanvas).Bar(startingData, areaChartOptions);
        var lineChartOptions = areaChartOptions;
        lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
    }
    //loop begin

    //endloop
}
```

This is the code i used to get data from

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getListIndex?Data=" + stringlist,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (datas) {
        showBarChart(datas.label, datas.index, datas.key);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

and this is the parent div which i append charts to

```
<div class="col-md-8 ">
    <p class="text-center infomess">
        <strong></strong>
    </p>
    <!-- begin loop -->
    <div class="metterpanel" id="metterpanel">
    </div>
    <!-- end loop -->
</div><!-- /.col -->
```

It is just show the last data from data source and this is the json i got from ajax:

```
{"success":true,"label":{"740100001":"01:18:26","740100003":"03:53:33","740100004":"09:12:04"},"index":{"740100001":0,"740100003":0,"740100004":0},"date":"11:11:00","fulldate":{"740100001":"17\/11\/2015","740100003":"18\/11\/2015","740100004":"25\/11\/2015"},"key":["740100001","740100003","740100004"]}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see `datas.key` in your json but you use it to pass to your function

Comment: no, datas is responed data from ajax, not from the json

Comment: In your json there is no `key` attribute. I assume the json you have shown is what is passed to the success callback, as such i do not see how `datas.key` can be anything but undefined from the code you have shown.  If the json shown is not what you are passing to the success callback what  are you passing to it?

Comment: @Quince sorry, my bad. i get another ajax result and not what i need to show. Updated my json string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you only see the last graph is because you are clearing the canvas you have drawn within each loop when you do this `document.getElementById('metterpanel').innerHTML +=`

To avoid this you could create a new element and append it to the target div. This will avoid your previous drawn canvases being cleared.

```
var newElement = $(' <div class="col-md-2 ">' + '<div class="meter">' + '<div>' +
            ' <canvas id="' + datakey + '"></canvas>' + ' <div class="ColProduct Product">' + '<div class="ProContent Pro-Name">' + datakey + ' </div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
$('#metterpanel').append(newElement);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/883g65xa/

Comment: OMG, you are my god!. i tried to figure out this 2 days and nothing show up until you appeared. Thank so much.

Comment: Thank you. we are so lucky to have a guy like you in our community